# How to get ID value from a DIV element using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, getelementsbytagname

I want to get ID value of this HTML markup.

Example: 123

```js
var id_query = document.querySelector("div.elementor-element-429a9ef");
var id_value = id_query.getElementsByTagName("div")[0].id;
console.log(id_query, id_value)
```

```html
<div class="elementor-column elementor-col-33 elementor-inner-column elementor-element elementor-element-c44908c" data-id="c44908c" data-element_type="column">
  <div class="elementor-widget-wrap elementor-element-populated">
    <div class="elementor-element elementor-element-429a9ef elementor-widget elementor-widget-heading" data-id="429a9ef" data-element_type="widget" id="1646" data-widget_type="heading.default">
      <div class="elementor-widget-container">
        <div class="elementor-heading-title elementor-size-default">2021-10-10 13:00:00</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're trying too hard. :) `querySelector` returns a single element. Simply get its ID value. Of course you can combine the statements or simply use `element.id` rather than defining a second variable.

Be sure to use more appropriate variable names. Your first statement didn't return a query. It returned an element.

```js
const element = document.querySelector("div.elementor-element-429a9ef");
const id = element.id;
console.log(id)
```

```html
<div class="elementor-column elementor-col-33 elementor-inner-column elementor-element elementor-element-c44908c" data-id="c44908c" data-element_type="column">
  <div class="elementor-widget-wrap elementor-element-populated">
    <div class="elementor-element elementor-element-429a9ef elementor-widget elementor-widget-heading" data-id="429a9ef" data-element_type="widget" id="1646" data-widget_type="heading.default">
      <div class="elementor-widget-container">
        <div class="elementor-heading-title elementor-size-default">2021-10-10 13:00:00</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use **dataset**

```js
var id_query = document.querySelector("div.elementor-element-429a9ef");

console.log(id_query.id)
console.log(id_query.dataset.id)
```

```html
<div class="elementor-column elementor-col-33 elementor-inner-column elementor-element elementor-element-c44908c" data-id="c44908c" data-element_type="column">
  <div class="elementor-widget-wrap elementor-element-populated">
    <div class="elementor-element elementor-element-429a9ef elementor-widget elementor-widget-heading" data-id="429a9ef" data-element_type="widget" id="1646" data-widget_type="heading.default">
      <div class="elementor-widget-container">
        <div class="elementor-heading-title elementor-size-default">2021-10-10 13:00:00</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I've reconstructed the snippet demo that you removed. Please familiarize yourself with the post editor.

Comment: `dataset` returns the data attributes. That's not what was asked for.